# Cropping strings at unsigned char

Tags: c++

I got a .d64 file that i have to read file names from.

In the file ~16 chars are allocated for the filename but most of the times the name is shorter than 16 chars, and that leaves me with the name of the file + alot of unsigned chars.

```
using namespace std;

void print_index() {

    int disk_id = 0;
    string disk_name;

    fstream d64(d64_file, ios::in | ios::binary);

    d64.seekg(sys.get_position(18, 0) + 143);

    disk_name.resize(19);
    d64.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&disk_name[0]), 19);

    d64.seekg(sys.get_position(18, 0) + 163);
    d64.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&disk_id), 1);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Disk name :" << disk_name << endl;
    cout << "Disk id   : " << hex << disk_id << endl << endl;
    cout << "##  " << "Name" << setw(20) << "Type" << setw(10) << "Size" << setw(10)
     << "Track" << setw(10) << "Sect" << endl;
     cout << "==============================================================" << endl;
     d64.close();
}
```

Here i read the filename from the file, which results in "EUREKA?????....."

I just need some way to identify unsigned chars!

Comment: What do you mean by "unsigned chars?"  Is `isprint()` the function you're seeking?

Comment: one unsigned char = one byte in the file, isn't that the same thing or am i missing something?

Comment: Do you mean a byte with the high bit set?  It would be useful if you'd post an *example* by showing the 19 bytes you've read (as hex) and then indicate where you think the end of the string should be and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you *are* reading 19 bytes, without caring about the actual length of the string. All those 19 bytes will be placed in the string, no questions asked.

So when you print the string, it will print all 19 "characters" in the string.

---

Also note the call to read the `disk_id` might not work exactly as you expect it to. If it's a single byte, then read it into an `uint8_t`, and then cast/assign it to an `int` if needed.

Comment: Yeah, you see the filenames are varying, so sometimes i need to read 16 chars and sometimes i need to read 8 and so on....

Comment: @user3234718 Exactly.  So what is the actual content of the file?  What is written if the file name is only 8 characters, but the program which writes it writes 16?

Comment: @user3234718 Is the actual length stored anywhere? Or is there a terminator?

Comment: The length isn't stored anywhere and there are no terminators in the file, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @user3234718 In that case it's impossible to know the length of the string, both before and after you read it. There is no way of terminating at the correct length. If you store variable-length string, you *need* some way of knowing the actual length.

Comment: My plan was to see where the first unsigned char appears and crop the string right there.
Funny thing is that it doesn't show up in Windows at all but in Linux it does show up.

Comment: @user3234718 On the bit-level there is no difference between an `unsigned char` and a `signed char`, it's all in the compiler. There's no way of differentiating between two bytes read from a file, to know if one is unsigned while another is not.